# Firefox multi-core when opening a list of bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, websites, multi-core

Is there a way to configure Firefox to use all available cores when opening a list of bookmarks?

For example, if I open a list of 10 bookmarks in one go, I would like Firefox to use all 4 cores available in my Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit laptop to speed up the rendering of the pages. But it seems like the only 1 core is used of the processor use in the System Monitor Widget.

Do I need to explicitly configure this in any way? According to Google, Firefox got multi-core improvements in the last 2 years. I am using version 19 but also downloaded version 20, so far with same results.

PS: I am not sure if this question is Ubuntu or Linux-specific, so if it is generic enough to Firefox that would make it more adequate to go to superuser.com or elsewhere, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Most "advanced" configuration settings are available via `about:config`. (Just for completeness, this is accessed by typing `about:config` in the address bar, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and accepting the caution.)

Now, the `about:config` page itself has a filter field: when I typed `core` in there, all I got was `services.sync.globalScore;0`. When I typed `cpu`, I drew a blank. And this is with Firefox 20 on a humble Dell Inspiron 1545 dual core machine.

If you can think of something more suitable to type into `about:config`, do try. *There are additional custom entries* that can be made in `about:config` but you may have to ask in mailing lists such as [support-firefox -- Firefox help community](https://lists.mozilla.org/listinfo/support-firefox) or [dev-apps-firefox -- Development discussion about Firefox](https://lists.mozilla.org/listinfo/dev-apps-firefox) for help on such advanced options. See [lists.mozilla.org Mailing Lists](https://lists.mozilla.org/listinfo) for more.